# Create function to get values from rows above based on a certain time frame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm currently analyzing a dataset of a Whatsapp group chat of 11 men in pandas, Python. The goal of the project is to predict the one who is going to respond to the message, with Random Forest.

For now I want to create an extra column of the people who are *in the conversation*, based on the time of the messages above. So for example, getting all the names of the people who messaged the group 15 minutes before a certain message.
It's okay if it's a list of people in 1 column, or that it'll be 11 columns (one per each person in chat) and that it's a True or False. For RF, the latter would be more handy,

The relevant columns I have:

```
    date_time           name    text
14  10-05-2014 19:36:39 John    Hi all
15  10-05-2014 19:46:42 Pete    Hey
16  10-05-2014 19:47:45 Joe     How are you
17  10-05-2014 19:48:48 Mike    Good
18  10-05-2014 19:50:14 Aaron   Fine
19  10-05-2014 19:54:44 Brad    What are you doing 
20  10-05-2014 20:08:16 Mike    Nothing
```

So what I want is something like:

```
    date_time           name    text                    in_convo
14  10-05-2014 19:36:39 John    Hi all                  NaN
15  10-05-2014 19:46:42 Pete    Hey                     John
16  10-05-2014 19:47:45 Joe     How are you             John, Pete
17  10-05-2014 19:48:48 Mike    Good                    John, Pete, Joe
18  10-05-2014 19:50:14 Aaron   Fine                    John, Pete, Joe, Mike
19  10-05-2014 19:54:44 Brad    What are you doing      Pete, Joe, Mike, Aaron
20  10-05-2014 20:08:16 Mike    Nothing                 Brad
```

This based on a period of 15 minutes.

Or for each person a seperate column, because I need to make dummies of them anyway.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Without using pandas it may be like this. Lets consider that:
*msg_list* contains the table with your messages, *row_num* contains the last row number,*name_list* is list of chat participants in the form ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', ... ]

```
from datetime import datetime
prec_row_num = row_num
output =  [False for cnt in len(name_list)] 
time_of_interest_minutes = 15

while prec_row_num > 0:
   prec_row_num = prec_row_num-1
   dtime = datetime.strptime(msg_list[prec_row_num, date_time], '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(msg_list[row_mum, date_time], '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
   if dtime.seconds//60 < time_of_interest_minutes:
      output[name_list.index(msg_list[prec_row_num,name])] = True
   else:
      break
```

The main idea is that you generate a timedelta object (i.e. *dtime*) and extract time difference from it. If the message was sent in the period of interest, then coloutput is m